# WP Subtitle - Formatting

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I’ve had no luck elsewhere and have often managed to find answers to stuff before, by looking at other people’s questions and answers on this site.

I’ve recently installed a WordPress plug-in (WP Subtitle) that allows me to assign a subtitle to posts and pages. Got a couple of problems though:

The following line is what displays the title of my blog posts as links in the Sidebar:

```
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?> </a>
```

I’ve amended it so the subtitle is displayed as well:

```
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title()+the_subtitle('<span class="subtitle">', '</span class="subtitle">') : the_ID(); ?></a>
```

The links themselves, work fine – but if the mouse only hovers over the title, only the title is highlighted, whereas if the mouse hovers over the subtitle, both the title and subtitle are highlighted (which is what I actually want). Does anybody know how I can achieve this please? For the title and subtitle to be highlighted regardless of which part of the link the user clicks on?

The second problem is that the code only seems to work for my posts, and doesn’t display the subtitle for my pages at all. (This is only in the Sidebar though – the individual pages and posts both display the title and subtitle fine).

If you need to see what I mean, my site is http://www.retelevise.com. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
SN.

Comment: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/different-link-text-colour.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's Going On

The issue here is that you are adding a layer of HTML inside the `a`, in the form of a `span`. Your CSS `:hover` rule only applies to itself, not to children. So when you hover over content directly inside the `a`, only content directly inside the `a` is highlighted. You can go two routes. The first involves removing the extra `span`, which you need to keep to change the color.

The second method is quite simple though, and just involves one extra line of code. We just need to add another selector to tell the browser to highlight all child `span`s as well as the `a`s themselves. Your current `:hover` selector is `.post-excerpt-title a:hover`. We just need to add in `.post-excerpt-title a:hover span`, and it'll work perfectly.

---

## Code

#### Current CSS: (Minus the comments)

```
.post-excerpt-title a:hover {
    color: #F29B06;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

#### New CSS:

```
.post-excerpt-title a:hover, .post-excerpt-title a:hover span {
    color: #F29B06;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

## Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - for explaining this so simply. It works perfectly!